# boosting the 'devtol' parameter in lme4

Tags: r, glm, lme4, confidence-interval

I am estimating a mixed model with `glmer` and experience the error

> Error in zeta(shiftpar, start = opt[seqpar1][-w]) : profiling detected new, lower deviance

I found a solution by "boosting" the `devtol` parameter. However, I don't know how and I can't find the solution.

Here is my model:

```r
m3.glmer = glmer(binExap ~ (1|id) + Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag5 + BroadQ, 
    data = CLnMD, 
    family = binomial(link="logit"), 
    nAGQ=1, control = glmerControl(optimizer = 'bobyqa', 
                                   optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)))
```

This is the code I am using for estimating the CIs:

```
KIsBoot <- confint.merMod(m3.glmer, method = "profile", nsim = 250)
```

Now where do I boost/how would I boost "devtol"?

Answer (score 2):

This is admittedly a bit obscure. `confint.merMod()` takes a `...` argument that gets passed to `profile.merMod`. `?profile.merMod` says:

> devtol: tolerance for fitted deviances less than baseline (supposedly
> minimum) deviance.

So, if you want to ignore this check completely,

```r
confint(m3.glmer, devtol = Inf)
```

should work. (You don't need `.merMod`, R figures that out automatically; "profile" is the default setting; and `nsim` is ignored unless `method = "boot"` [we should add a warning!])

However, I would also say a little bit pessimistically that if you're getting this error your profile CIs might not be very reliable ... try visualizing the profile as well (`pp <- profile(m3.glmer, devtol = Inf); lattice::xyplot(pp)`) to make sure it looks reasonable (i.e. at least monotonic!)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That clears things up for me. Highly appreciated.